# VKApi для Kotlin

Tags: vkontakte-api, kotlin

Как импортировать VKApi в Kotlin-проект? Откуда его скачать,  как установить?

Comment: Java SDK скачайте и дергайте из Kotlin: https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin/Python/C++/etc. - какая разница то?:)

kotlin - это лишь инструмент отсылки и получения запросов.

Открываете [документацию](https://vk.com/dev/methods) и отправляете POST / GET запросы через, например, `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: Такк а методы самой апи можно разве использовать не импортируя?

Comment: Прост на Python надо было сперва через pip VKApi скачать, и импортировать в файл